# Calculate gradient of trained network

Tags: numpy, neural-network, gradient, autograd

assume I got a trained model, I am trying to calculate it's Jacobin (trying to understand some it's mathematical properties after training). I am trying to use `autograd` as follow:

```
from autograd import jacobian
jacobian_pred=jacobian(model.predict)
jacobian_pred(x)
```

where x is from my training set. It raises an error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len()
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: add a simple reproducible example here or in Colab, specifically showing type and composition of `model`

Comment: The input for the model is np.ndarray of size 7X151X2 (all floats), the output is of np.ndarray size 6 float. In the first layer the input gets zero_padding to size 21X191X2. The model includes approximately 45 layers - some dense and some convolution, and include several different activation function.  In summary, it includes more than 27 million trainable params. Any additional information?